# Limiting number of checkable radios in a page

Tags: jquery

Evening all,

Been trying to do this for a day now but can't figure it out.

I've got a page filled with 5 groups of radio selects, with 3 selects in each group.

```
GROUP 1   | GROUP 2   | GROUP 3   | GROUP 4   | GROUP 5
radio 1-1 | radio 1-1 | radio 3-1 | radio 4-1 | radio 5-1
radio 1-2 | radio 2-2 | radio 3-2 | radio 4-2 | radio 5-2
radio 1-3 | radio 2-3 | radio 3-3 | radio 4-3 | radio 5-3
```

Of course, user is limited to selecting only one radio within each group, but I want to be able to limit the total number of radios on the whole page a user can select ... to, say, 3 ... then all the other radios would be deselected.

Would also like to display what radios are currently selected in a separate area ... but I can't figure out how to make jquery work with multiple radio groups! With checkboxes it's simply :checked ... but since checking a radio deselects other radio in same group, don't know how to emulate that.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: That would be pretty strange behavior. What happens if the user changes their mind and wants to pick one of the newly disabled options?

Comment: When you say *"all others would be deselected"* do you really mean *all* others? Or do you mean the most recent previous selection? Or the least recent previous selection?

Comment: @ Michael Haren: I would want to put X's next to each item in the separated list so they could remove items they no longer wish.

Comment: @patrick dw: If this is simply too much of a hassle to implement, I may simply end up going with just showing the user how many checkboxes are checked and telling them they've gone over the allowed limit and disabling the submit button (along with some actual checking behind the scenes if they've got JS off, of course).

Comment: I don't think it would be too hard to implement, but the requirements aren't clear. When 3 are selected, when happens when the user goes to select a fourth? Does the most recent one they selected become unselected? Or the oldest one? Also, if you provided some HTML, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this in 30 mins, I know it can be done much better. Probably you will get idea how to go about it.

Its too late for me now. May be tomorrow i might make it a better version of it.

http://jsfiddle.net/eGZQV/